# What are the advantages of using an STL clone?

Tags: c++, stl

- When would I need an alternative to C++'s STL?
- Are there any advantages to using an alternative STL?
- Which ones would you recommend, if any?

Sorry for these noob bullet points, but I see a lot of products that ship with different STLs linked in and was wondering when something like that is useful.

Comment: If you mention some specific STL implementation you might get more specific information.

Comment: You're right. I'm happy with the native STL for now. I'm sure there's plenty of Stacks for the implementation if\when I choose one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about alternative implementations of STL, rather than alternatives to the STL.

There's a few reasons you might use a 3rd party STL implementation, rather than the default one provided by your compiler.

1. Consistency - you might be using multiple compilers and want to ensure you get the same behavior on each platform.
2. Speed - An implementation might be more efficient than the one provided by your compiler.
3. Completeness - Your compilers default library might not provide the full complement of STL features. (This may only be for old compilers, or compilers for embedded systems, or for C++11 features).
4. Extra features - Some implementations of STL provide features like improved debugging of invalid iterators etc, which may not be in your compilers implementation.

Obviously not all these hold for all compilers .. but there are certainly cases where 3rd party STLs can be helpful.

As for implementations: you can find a list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library#Implementations)

Comment: That all makes sense. So I guess it's not a process of choosing the STL implementation off the bat, the problem will arise and the STL alternative will fix it. Thanks for the quick and easy answer.

Comment: The 'completeness' may not only hold to *old* compilers nowadays. The alternative library may provide more C++11 features than the one shipped with the compiler.

Comment: For completeness, you should add STL implementations tailored for memory-constrained embedded systems.

Answer (score 2):

Michael's provided a good answer - just a couple points to add:

- "Speed" isn't just a linear thing where you can say decisively that STL implementation X is N% faster than STL Y: there are implementation choices trading off speed and memory usage in various usage scenarios.  For example, a "short string optimisation" may allow very short strings to be stored directly in the string object rather than in heap memory; implementations may have slightly different choices about how generously to resize containers exceeding their current capacity.
- Binary interoperability is a big deal: if you need to call a library function that's pre-compiled to accept STL X objects, you can't simply link the library and feed it the STL Y equivalents: there could be differences in the mangled names preventing linking, the binary layout of the objects may well be different, and even if not and you forced such a call - the operations your client code performs on those objects may not be be everything the library code expects or needs (i.e. wouldn't maintain the same invariants).
- Thread safety is a noteworthy example of "extra features"... e.g. many early STLs had errors with Copy-on-Write string implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Another point: some STL implementations allow you to disable the use of exceptions, possibly using a custom global error handler instead of C++ exceptions.  This is less important nowadays, but for a long time, a lot of systems had exceptions disabled for various reasons, and there are still a few outlier systems on which exceptions are discouraged or completely unsupported.